# Spring batch job exit status for failed step

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, upgrade

I recently upgraded an old application using `Spring Batch 2.2.0 to 3.0.5`. I made the necessary changes to the DB tables and some minute code changes related to parameter APIs.

Now when I run the application it is working but if a step's exit status is FAILED the job's exist status is set to COMPLETED. This is causing issues as our application code treats this as a successful execution. I am getting around it by adding a code snippet in `afterJob()` where I check the `stepExecution` list and set the job exit status manually, but shouldn't the Spring Batch framework take care of the exit status?

Is there anything that I missed while upgrading?

Ref: http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/configureJob.html

Answer (score 4):

If you are using the Java based configuration, you could add `.on(ExitStatus.FAILED.getExitCode()).fail()` to a step that should cause the job's exit status to be `FAILED`:

```
jobBuilderFactory.get("jobName")
    .start(firstStep())
    .next(secondStep()).on(ExitStatus.FAILED.getExitCode()).fail()
    .next(thirdStep())
    .end()
    .build()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `<fail>` transition element inside `<job>` to  instruct a Job to stop with a BatchStatus and ExisStatus of FAILED.

```
<step id="step2" parent="s2">
    <fail on="FAILED" />
    <next on="*" to="step3"/>
</step>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Decider on that job and that decider call a class like this:

```
public class JobDecider implements JobExecutionDecider  {

  /* @Autowired
    private JobOperator jobOperator;*/

    @Override
    public FlowExecutionStatus decide(JobExecution arg0, StepExecution stepExecution) {

    JobParameters jp = arg0.getJobParameters();

    if(!stepExecution.getExitStatus().getExitCode().equals("COMPLETED"))
    {
        return FlowExecutionStatus.FAILED;
    }
    else 
    {
        //System.out.println("*******Job Decider ******* With Passed State ");

        return FlowExecutionStatus.COMPLETED;
    }

    }

}
```